# Cannot access server in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, deployment

I started a docker image using

```
docker run --interactive --tty node_web_1
```

And the running server inside the container successfully prints

```
Running on http://localhost:8080
```

in the console. I have exposed port 8080 in the Dockerfile. So in my understanding, when I call http://localhost:8080 in the browser in windows, I should access the server in the container, right? I get no reply though....

How do I go about finding the error? I executed the command

```
docker-machine ls
```

as suggested here [How to access Docker container's web server from host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191815/cant-access-containers-web-server-from-host-what-am-i-doing-wrong) but apparently I have no docker-machines running? What are those machines? Do I need them? I have only docker for windows installed, no additionall packages or shells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to publish your port

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it node_web_1
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped. Could you tell me why EXPOSE is not sufficient though? Does it basically mean I can send requests from the dockerized server, but I cannot sent requests to it? So EXPOSE is just one-directional? Or what am I missing here?

Comment: @Phil i think it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker